# Repeatable HTTP requests in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x, json, http, python-requests

I have a simple python script that's repeating a HTTP response/request. I would like to know how I could have constructed this better, particularly if there's a way I could have incorporated the slice operator to cut down on my variable usage.

For context - the response contained a JSON string in between the `<ExecuteResult>` flags that I'm removing currently with `split()`

```
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint

url = "<redacted>"
cookies = {<redacted>}
headers = {<redacted>}
data="<redacted>"

submissions = input("How many submissions to create:")

while submissions > 0:
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
    xml_string = response.content
    json_file = xml_string.split('<ExecuteResult>')[1]
    json_file = (json_file.split('</ExecuteResult>')[0]).replace("\\", "")
    json_response = json.loads(json_file)
    print "Created Id: " + json_response['_entity']['Id']
    submissions -= 1
```

Comment: Do your `data` and/or `url` actually change for the different submissions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are making many requests, it is worth it to have a look at [`requests.Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects). This re-uses the connection to the server for subsequent requests (and also the headers and cookies).

I would also start separating your different responsibilities. One might be global constants (like your header and cookies), one a function that actually does the submission, one that creates the session and does each submission and then some code under a [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard that executes the code.

```
import requests
import json

COOKIES = {<redacted>}
HEADERS = {<redacted>}

def post(session, url, data):
    """Use session to post data to url.
    Returns json object with execute result"""
    response = session.post(url, data=data)
    json_file = response.content.split('<ExecuteResult>')[1]
    json_file = (json_file.split('</ExecuteResult>')[0]).replace("\\", "")
    return json.loads(json_file)


def post_submisssions(url, data, n):
    """Create a session and post `n` submissions to `url` using `data`."""
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers.update(HEADERS)
    session.cookies = COOKIES

    for _ in xrange(n):
        json_response = post(session, url, data)
        print "Created Id:", json_response['_entity']['Id']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "<redacted>"
    data = "<redacted>"
    post_submisssions(url, data, input("How many submissions to create:"))
```

I also added some rudimentary [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)s.

---

You could also change your parsing by using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def post(session, url, data):
    """Use session to post data to url.
    Returns json object with execute result"""
    response = session.post(url, data=data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
    return json.loads(soup.find('ExecuteResult'.lower()).replace("\\", ""))
```

Answer (score 7):

I'll start with the obvious:

```
while submissions > 0:
    ...
    submissions -= 1
```

can be transformed into:

```
for _ in xrange(submissions):
    ...
```

There are other changes that I think would make the code slightly better, albeit not necessarily more pythonic:

- `submissions` should probably be named `submission_count` (thanks, [Ludisposed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/140549/ludisposed)!).
- You appear to be parsing HTML using `string.split()`. It might work OK now, but if you need to add more functionality in the future this approach will be very cumbersome. Try using a library instead (for example, [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)).
- You're not using the `pprint` import, so you might as well remove that line.

Comment: `submissionCount` does not adhere PEP8. Functions and variables should be `snake_case`

Comment: @Ludisposed You are right. Thanks! I edited the answer.